# fileku.write(sys.argv[i+3]+'\n') IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, argv, sys

i'm still new in python,i want to create a program that can read/write/append text file depending on the command line argument.

here is my code :

import sys

```
def prosesfile():
        fileku=open(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
        if(sys.argv[2] == 'w'):
                for i in range(5):
                        fileku.write(sys.argv[i+3]+'\n')
                print('proses tulis file selesai.')
        elif(sys.argv[2] == 'r'):
                for i in fileku:
                        print(i)
                print('proses baca selesai.')
        elif(sys.argv[2] == 'a'):
                for i in range(5):
                        fileku.write(sys.argv[i+3]+'\n')
                print('proses append file selesai.')

prosesfile()
```

then i tried to execute:

```
python3 program.py textfile.txt w word1 word2
```

but then i got an error :

```
File "program.py", line 14, in prosesfile
fileku.write(sys.argv[i+3]+'\n')
```

IndexError: list index out of range

What happen? is there anything wrong with my code?
thanks :)

Comment: You didn't provide those extra 5 arguments when invoking your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your program with

```
python3 program.py textfile.txt w word1 word2
```

you will have a total of 5 command line arguments. The loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    fileku.write(sys.argv[i+3]+'\n')
```

will try to access elements beyond that.

Change to this:

```
for arg in sys.argv[3:]:
    fileku.write(arg+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop: `for i in range(5):` variable `i` is assigned values 0, 1,2,3,4; so when you try to access `sys.argv[i+3]` `i+3` is 3,4,5,6,7, but you only have 4 elements in `sys.argv`.

Comment: so if i change to for i in range(10):,what happen? i've tried but still error?? :|